# inaccurate colormap [FLIR TOOLS] in .jpeg thermal image

Tags: colorbar, imaging, infrared, color-palette, flir

I am currently working on a project with a thermal datasets I found online. Basically I just need to extract the .csv from the thermal image. Because the datasets only provide the jpg format, I tried to use the FLIR TOOLS to get the temperature value out of the image.

[image: the generated image from FLIR TOOLS]

[image: the image I'm currently working with]

As seen, the FLIR TOOLS detect that the temperature of the face is 74.7 at the highest, which makes no sense, is this possible to get the 'closest' value to? or it is impossible because the .jpg format? Can anyone recommend me on how to get the temperatrue from a Thermal image? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general - you can't get temperature from plain grayscale JPEG. It has no temperature calibration data which relate gray level to real temperature. Real FLIR images contain embedded metadata for that.